# How do I hide HTML/JavaScript code in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

For a customer's high school project, I have created a static but relatively complex website using HTML and Javascript only. Now, before customer pays me, he wants to have a look at the website. Therefore, he requested me to host it temporarily on AWS S3. But I am afraid that he will click on **view source** and download all the code, and might not pay me afterward.

Is there a way to hide my code in the above scenario, except using team viewer, where the customer accesses my personal computer.

Comment: Don't you have a contract that prohibits them from doing this? If they download the code before paying you, you sue them.

Comment: You could obfuscate the code. He'd be able to download it, but it won't be in a form that they can easily work with for future enhancements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Luckily, I found a way to achieve this. The following code can be used:

```
    <head>
<script>function myFunction() 
{   
    var g1 = new Date();      //Today
    var g2 = new Date('2020-10-06'); //The date from which trial version should stop working
    if (g1 > g2)
    {
        alert("Trial Period Expired");
    }
    else
    {
        //-------------Normal code goes here-------
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

</body>
```

Now, just encrypt the code using some free online tools so that the Date can't be altered by the user.

Comment: To the person who downvoted, at least provide feedback and the reason.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

The best you can do is send some screenshots, but of course this isn't very interactive, nor a good way to evaluate a website.